# Can't use pendulum to parse dates in Series, but works one by one

Tags: python, pandas, date, pendulum

I'm trying to parse dates using `pendulum`. I have a `TimeStamp` date, so I did the following:

```
df['aux']=df['Date'].dt.date
df['p_date']=df.aux.apply(lambda x: pendulum.parse(x))
```

Which brings the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'DateTime' object has no attribute 'nanosecond'
```

But if I do, something like:

```
pendulum.parse(df.aux[0])
```

It gets parsed no problem. I thought `apply(lambda x:)` applied the same function to all rows of the `Series` , but now it isn't working. What's happening?

Sample code:

```
dates=pd.Series(['2018-03-20','2019-03-21'])
dates.apply(lambda x: pendulum.parse(x)) #Doesn't work
pendulum.parse(dates[0]) #Works
```

Comment: Why don't you use `pd.to_datetime(dates)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use .naive() at the end

```
dates.apply(lambda x: pendulum.parse(x).naive()) #works
```

See this thread: https://github.com/sdispater/pendulum/issues/246

> It seems that pandas tries to convert the timezone aware datetime to
>   it's own timestamp representation, but that conversion isn't triggered
>   with the naive datetime. I don't think anyone is at fault here, as a
>   user of both pendulum and pandas it makes it difficult to use them
>   together.

Answer (score 0):

Since pandas dose not have nanosecond , in [github](https://github.com/sdispater/pendulum/issues/246), so convert it to `str`, instead of received following error

> 'DateTime' object has no attribute 'nanosecond'

```
dates.apply(lambda x: str(pendulum.parse(x)))
Out[256]: 
0    2018-03-20T00:00:00+00:00
1    2019-03-21T00:00:00+00:00
dtype: object
```